# Entity Framework: Model doesn't reflect DB

Tags: entity-framework

I'm probably thinking about this all wrong but I have the following db tables:

[image]

When I run the EF Wizard in VS2008 I get the following model:

[image]

You'll notice that in the EF model shows that the Entity has no field for EntityTypeID or EntityStatusId.  Instead it shows it as a navigation property, so the field appears to not be addressable when I instantiate an Entity (pardon the terminology confusion:  Entity is a Table/Class in my name space not in the EF namespace).  How can I assign an EntityTypeID and StatusTypeID when instantiating an Entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the entity framework hides foreign key ID properties and shows navigation properties instead. There is a lengthy discussion about why it does that, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2008/10/27/foreign-keys-in-the-conceptual-and-object-models.aspx). The usual means of assigning a reference to another entity is to assign the entity instance, rather than the foreign key ID value, like this:

```
var foo = new Entity();
var status = (from .... select ...).FirstOrDefault();
foo.StatusCodes = status;
```

However, it is possible to assign a foreign key ID directly, if you happen to know what it is:

```
foo.StatusCodesReference = new EntityKey(
   "MyEntityContextName.StatusCodesEntitySetName", "StatusCodeId", value);
```

Obviously, substitute the real values in the above.

Comment: OK I get it, I tried it in my code and it works.  I need a serious reorientation from Linq to SQL -> Linq to Entities.  Thanks for your help (again) :-)